# Добавление правила в sepolicy (Android)

Tags: android, selinux

Добрый день. 
Пытаюсь скомпилировать Андроид. И столкнулся с такой проблемой
Появляется сообщение. У меня были такие ошибки в `dmesg`

```
avc: denied { search } for pid=2756 comm="fastrvc" name="2054" dev="proc" ino=9360 scontext=u:r:fastrvc_native:s0 tcontext=u:r:hal_allocator_default:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
avc: denied { open } for pid=2756 comm="fastrvc" path="/proc/2054/comm" dev="proc" ino=9384 scontext=u:r:fastrvc_native:s0 tcontext=u:r:hal_allocator_default:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

По тупому поставить правило для sepolicy

```
allow fastrvc_native hal_allocator_default:dir search;
```

не вышло. 
Я получил исключение при компиляции

```
:ERROR 'unknown type hal_allocator_default' at token ';'
```

Я поискал через adb shell - это, как я понимаю, процесс

```
/proc/2054 #> ls -Z
....
u:r:hal_allocator_default:s0 comm
....
```

Вообще домен hal_allocator_default определен в [system/sepolicy/private](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/master/private/hal_allocator_default.te)
Но в папке `device/XXX/YYY/sepolicy` этот домен использовать не получается

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему с этими `avc: denied` сообщениями?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать `hal_allocator_server` вместо `hal_allocator_default`.